# How to pass a parentNode.id as a parameter to an element out of the querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I have these elements created inside a "querySelector('ul'). It's working property.

I want the "blue-Save" button to have the same function as the "yellow-Save".

But the Blue-save button was created in the HTML file, and the Yellow-Save button was created in JavaScript to listen to an event from the "querySelector('ul').

Is there anyway I can just link the Blue-Save to react as if I was clicking in the Yellow-Save?

(I'm sorry if I didn't explain it property or If it seems too confused, this is my first application, It doesn't seems too organized but I'm focused in making things work before dive in 'well developed apps').

Thank You Everyone!

[image: ScreenShot from The Application]

```js
var todoList = {
  todos: [],
  addTodo: function (todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      /*the name of the property (even if it is the same name as the parameter) never change. Only the value, which follows in this case is following the parameter*/
      completed: false
    });
  },
  changeTodo: function (position, todoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
  },
  deleteTodo: function (position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
  },
  toggleCompleted: function (position) {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    /*Here we flip the boolean to his oposite value. if todo.completed is equal false, so changes it to true, and so on. */
  },
  toggleAll: function () {
    // recording the number of todos and completed todos
    var totalTodos = this.todos.length;
    var completedTodos = 0;
    // get the number of completed todos.
    this.todos.forEach(function (todo) {
      if (todo.completed === true) {
        completedTodos++;
      }
    });
    this.todos.forEach(function (todo) {
      // Case 1: If everything is true, make everything.
      if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
        todo.completed = false;
        // Case 2: Otherwise, make everything true.
      } else {
        todo.completed = true;
      }
    });
  }
};

var handlers = {
  addTodo: function () {
    var addTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('add-todo-text-input');
    todoList.addTodo(addTodoTextInput.value);
    addTodoTextInput.value = '';
    view.displayTodos();

    
  },
  changeTodo: function (position) {
    var changeTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('change-todo-text-input');
    todoList.changeTodo(position, changeTodoTextInput.value);
    changeTodoTextInput.value = '';
    view.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteTodo: function (position) {
    todoList.deleteTodo(position);
    view.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function (position) {
    todoList.toggleCompleted(position);
    view.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleAllButton: function () {
    todoList.toggleAll();
    view.displayTodos();
  }
};

var view = {
  displayTodos: function () {
    var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
    todosUl.innerHTML = '';

    todoList.todos.forEach(function (todo, position) {
      var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
      var todoTextWithCompletion = '';

      if (todo.completed === true) {
        todoTextWithCompletion = todo.todoText;
        todoLi.classList.add('item-completed');
      } else {
        todoTextWithCompletion = todo.todoText;
      }

      todoLi.id = position;
      todoLi.textContent = todoTextWithCompletion;
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createEditButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createToggleButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createSaveButton());
      todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);
    }, this);
  },
  createDeleteButton: function () {
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.textContent = '\u2715';
    deleteButton.className = 'delete-button';
    return deleteButton;
  },
  createToggleButton: function () {
    var toggleButton = document.createElement('button');
    toggleButton.textContent = '\u2713';
    toggleButton.className = 'toggle-button';
    return toggleButton;
  },
  createSaveButton: function () {
    var saveButton = document.createElement('button');
    saveButton.textContent = 'Save';
    saveButton.className = 'save-button';
    return saveButton;
  },
  createEditButton: function () {
    var editButton = document.createElement('button');
    editButton.textContent = '\u270E';
    editButton.className = 'edit-button';
    return editButton;
  },
  setUpEventListeners: function () {

    var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');

    todosUl.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      
      // Get the element that was clicked on.
      var elementClicked = event.target;

      // Check if elementClicked is a delete button.
      if (elementClicked.className === 'delete-button') {
        handlers.deleteTodo(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));
        



      } else if (elementClicked.className === 'toggle-button') {
        handlers.toggleCompleted(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));
      } else if (elementClicked.className === 'save-button') {
        handlers.changeTodo(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));

        

      } else if (elementClicked.className === 'edit-button') {
        
      }
    });
  }
};

view.setUpEventListeners();
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    background: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

h1 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.add-button {
    background-color: rgb(68, 165, 230); /* Blue */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:20%;    
}

.add-button:hover {
    background-color :rgb(53, 127, 177); /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.save-change-button {
    background-color: rgb(68, 165, 230); /* Blue */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:20%;    
}

.save-change-button:hover {
    background-color :rgb(53, 127, 177); /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.toggle-all-button {
    background-color: rgb(38, 156, 38); /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;   
}

.toggle-all-button:hover {
    background-color : rgb(36, 114, 36);  /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.edit-button {
    background-color: rgb(219, 208, 50); /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.edit-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(185, 175, 26); /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.toggle-button {
    background-color: rgb(38, 156, 38); /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.toggle-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(36, 114, 36); /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.delete-button {
    background-color: rgb(168, 44, 44); /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.delete-button:hover {
    background-color :rgb(128, 31, 31); /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.save-button {
    background-color: rgb(219, 208, 50); /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.save-button:hover {
    background-color :rgb(185, 175, 26); /* Green */
    color: white;
}

.add-input {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 78%;
}

.edit-input {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 78%;
}

.item-completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.555);
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Todo List</title>
 <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

  <h1>Todo List</h1>

 <div>
  <input id="add-todo-text-input" class="add-input" placeholder="Add a New Todo to Your List" type="text">
    <button class="add-button" onclick="handlers.addTodo()">Add</button>
 </div>

  <ul>
 </ul>

 <div id="edit-todo"">
   <input id="change-todo-text-input" class="edit-input" placeholder="Add the Changes Your Want to Make" type="text">
   <button class="save-change-button">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div id="toggle-all"">
  <button class="toggle-all-button" onclick="handlers.toggleAllButton()">Toggle All</button>
 </div>

</div>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you add yellow button, why don't  you change blue one as well. Add class or something to blue btn

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common class to both blue and yellow buttons, and attach a click event by the class name like below

```
$(".custom_save_button").on("click", function() {
   //your code
});
```

Comment: That's it! but he's not using jquery nor he has jquery tag

Comment: I've tried it, but the function in the Yellow-Save as a parameter: 

      `} else if (elementClicked.className === 'save-button') {
        handlers.changeTodo(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));`

Comment: check my answer

Comment: You dont necessarily need to pass the parentNode.id. You can just use `$(this).parent().attr("id");` inside your click function to get the parent id.

Comment: @Dimith Thats true but he never said he was using JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating that button, sharing the same class won't just work as expected, instead use delegated events which allow you to attach events on new elements added to the DOM

Add a common class for both and then add an event listener for that class using event delegation.

For this example Let's suppose you chose the class name: `stack_class`

```
//I added this function for you to be able to know if an element has a class
function hasClass( target, className ) {
    return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(target.className);
}

//you could change body to the closest parent's selector both buttons share 
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
    if(hasClass(clickedElement, "stack_class")) {
         //create your functionality for both buttons here
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct...but I can't find the right way to do it in my code. I've included the whole code here, JS, html and CSS. Maybe someone can take a look at how it works and help me out. I'm a beginner...Thank you!

Comment: @RenatoGuimaraesNunes did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a common class to both buttons, then you can add the same event listener to all buttons that have that class. Here is a simple example:

```js
var saveButton = document.createElement('button');
saveButton.textContent = 'Save';
saveButton.className = 'save-button yellow-button';

body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(saveButton);

buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('save-button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    alert('Hello!');    
  });
}
```

```css
.yellow-button {
  background: #ffff00;
}
.blue-button {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<button class="save-button blue-button">Save</button>
```