# How can I use the same parameter for a button out of an object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button with document.createElement('button'); inside a `<ul>`; and passing as document.createElement('li'). Every time I add a new `<li>` to the DOM, the button will be display in front that `<li>` added. And the button will take its `parentNode.Id` as a argument to access it in the object and invoking a function.

But, I have also created a button in my HTML file, which is outside of the `<ul>`, and it is not display in the `<li>` element. It's a independent button. How can I make this button act the same way the button created in the `<li>` element acts? Is there any way I can use the same property in a button outside of that object?

#### I want to have one single button that saves any changes I made. Not, one button for every `<li>` element.

I've tried giving them the same `className`, but it doesn't work. Because the button created in the Javascript file will display in every `<li>` added in my application. The button that is display in front of the `<li>` is getting that specific '`<li>` `parentNode.Id` as an argument.  If you take a look at the piece of code I put here, you will see the last line in the Javascript code, the parameter is taking.

```
 displayTodos: function () {
  var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
  todosUl.innerHTML = '';
  todoList.todos.forEach(function (todo, position) {
   var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
   todoLi.id = position;
   todoLi.appendChild(this.createSaveButton());
   todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);
  }, this);
 },

createSaveButton: function () {
 var saveButton = document.createElement('button');
 saveButton.textContent = 'Save';
 saveButton.className = 'save-button';
 return saveButton;
},

setUpEventListeners: function () {
 var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
 todosUl.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var elementClicked = event.target;
  if (elementClicked.className === 'save-button') {
   handlers.changeTodo(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));
}


<ul>
</ul>
<button id="save-change-button" class="save-change-button">Save</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes to pass parameters to your reusable html5 elements.

Comment: How can you have one save `<button>` outside of the list to save a specific `<li>`? I can understand that the save button saves the entire state of all `<li>`, but not one specific one.

Comment: @seebiscuit If I can save the entire state of all <li>, I think that would work too. As you can only edit one item at a time. Saving the entire list would work for me too. Any idea how I can do this? I can upload the entire code here too. It's a simple Todo List. (My first project). I've tried to ask here, but I my struggling to explain my problem. I still don't have a good technical vocabulary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922876/how-to-pass-a-parentnode-id-as-a-parameter-to-an-element-out-of-the-queryselecto

Comment: I saw your other post. It looks like the save button is used to save an edit to *a single todo*. You're going to need to create an input for every `<li>` and you can have one save button that saves all the changes that are still pending. Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

To make your idea work, you're going to have to have an `input` element inside every `li`. It should be hidden, until the `edit` button is pressed. I would add an `edit` class to the `li` and using CSS reveal the `input` element. A `cancel` button, would remove the `edit` class from the `li`.

So if the rendered view looks like:

```
<ul class="todos">
  <li>
   <span class="todo-text">Old todo</span>
   <input type="text" value="Old todo" />
  </li>
  <li class="edit">
   <span class="todo-text">Old todo #2</span>
   <input type="text" value="Old todo #2" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where the CSS would be like

```
li input,
li.edit .todo-text {
  display: none;
}

li.edit input {
 display: inline;
}
```

Which toggles between the current `li` and the change `input`.

If you want to save the state of all editing `<li>` when a single save button is clicked, first you have to bind an event listener to the `<button>`:

```
const saveButton = document.createElement('button');
const body = document.getElementByTag('body'); 
// I chose body to append the button to, but you can append it to your main container

body.appendChild(saveButton);
saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveState);
```

Now, `saveState` will be defined as:

```
function saveState(e) {
  let data = [];
  const todos = document.querySelector('ul.todos li.edit');

  // On save check all "changing" <li>
  Array.from(todos).forEach((li, i) => { 
    const editInput = li.querySelector("input"); // Get input inside <li>

    if (editInput != null) {
      const span = li.querySelector("todo-text");
      span.textContent = editInput.value; // add the edit text to the span
    }

    li.classList.remove("edit") // Remove the edit class
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm trying to follow it. But to be honest I can't connect the dots...I think it's a leak of knowledge from me... I've tried copy your code and implement in my project...Thank You!

Comment: I'll be happy to improve the answer. Let's break it down. What's the first thing that you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you want to update a specific todo. In order to that, you can make use of the following code.

```js
// id of the clicked todo
var todoID = -1;
// Your Todo array
var todos = [
    {
        id:1,
        description: "Exercise",
        isCompleted:false
    },
    {
        id:2,
        description: "Shopping",
        isCompleted:false
    },

];


// update specific todo item in the todo array according to the id
function updateToDos(id ,newDesc){
    
    for (todo in todos){
        if(todos[todo].id == id){
            todos[todo].description = newDesc;
        }
    }
}


var ul = document.getElementById('todos');

// set event listener at in UL to get info about clicked li
ul.onclick = function(e) {

    // get clicked li element, Note: e.srcElement for IE support
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    // get id of the li element
    todoID = target.id;
    // get todo editing input field
    var modifiedToDoDesc = document.getElementById("edit-todo-input");
    // set the value of the input field = innerHTML of clicked li  
    modifiedToDoDesc.value = target.innerHTML;
    
};

var btnSave = document.getElementById('btnSave');

btnSave.onclick = function(){

    var modifiedToDoDesc = document.getElementById("edit-todo-input").value;

    updateToDos(todoID, modifiedToDoDesc);
    // Update the todos in the UI here
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="todos" onClick="hello">
        <li id="1">One</li>
        <li id="2">Two</li>

    </ul>
        <input type="text" id="edit-todo-input">
        <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```